# Usage of “when” or “while” in this context

Tags: when

> He left the house *_* I was still sleeping

Would this sentence be better completed with *when* or with *while*?

Answer (score 8):

The choice really hinges on the durative or punctual aspect of the particular verb (or verb construction, like *was sleeping*) in the adverbial clause. To illustrate the difference:

He left the house **when** the taxi arrived. (*taxi arrived*: punctual, point-in-time aspect)

He left the house **while** I was still sleeping. (*I was still sleeping*: durative, extended aspect)

There  is sometimes a choice, to indicate the intended aspect:

He was in the playground when the children arrived. (They all came essentially at the same time.)

He was in the playground while the children arrived. (They came over a period of time.) (Here, *children were arriving* would probably be preferable.)

Comment: I thought that was GR. Or at least fit for ELL.